# Using replace-regexp-in-string without case folding

Tags: let-binding, case-folding

I'm trying to use replace-regexp-in-string (see function below) and I need to detect the boundary between a lower case and upper case character. Apparently let-binding case-fold-search to nil doesn't work? I'm trying this in the latest pretest

GNU Emacs 25.0.94.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F1603)) of 2016-05-17

as well as

GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org

(obviously on a Mac)

```el
(defun spread-upcase-filename (filename)
  "fooBar.h => F O O  B A R . H"
  (let ((case-fold-search nil)
        (str (replace-regexp-in-string "\\([a-z0-9]\\)\\([A-Z]+\\)"
                                       "\\1\x01\\2" filename t)))
    (setq str (mapconcat 'identity (split-string str "" t) " "))
    ;;(setq str (replace-regexp-in-string "\x01" "" str t))
    (upcase str)))
```

From the documentation I've seen so far, case-fold-search is supposed to be
dynamically-bound rather than lexically-bound, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @Drew: really?  it looks like a completely different issue.

Comment: @Stefan: Right. Voted to close the wrong one. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you *haven't* bound `case-fold-search` in the scope of the the call to `replace-regexp-in-string`.

See the difference between <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `let` and <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `let*`

Comment: D'oh, I had moved it up and totally lost track of this. Thx.